# Monitor keyboard access on the Windows lock screen

Tags: malware, windows-10, keyboard

I don't do this very often, but every time I lock the screen in Windows [Win+L], the keyboard (and sometimes the mouse) stops responding and it goes straight into the password field and it starts typing random characters (like `Mud2Cx22`).

It looks like it only does it on the lock screen (I assume it would interfere with normal use if it were to do it always). **Is there a way to monitor if and when my keyboard is sending data, and what is triggering it?**

I don't see any suspicious connections on the PC or the router. I do full malware scans daily, and Windows is updated... I'm out of ideas...

Comment: ok, so it is truly random characters

Comment: There will be no way to monitor what's going on on the lock screen.

Comment: Like you, we can only speculate on what is going on and if it is malware. As for the ultimate question you ask, that's for another site.

Comment: Is your Windows 10 on the latest version and is full updated? Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try switching out all current USB devices. Though rare, there *are* [USB devices used for targeted attack](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/heres-a-list-of-29-different-types-of-usb-attacks/), such as keystroke injection.

Another possibility is that a nearby device is using the same protocol as a wireless keyboard or mouse, so test this by using wired-only devices for a while, or use different devices with their own wireless dongles.